# dyld: symbol not found after upgrade to Xcode 4.5 from Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: xcode4.5

my app was work fine when running in iOS 6 , but when i running it in iOS 5 or below, it shows   lots kind of following message, but apps can still runs though.

2012-09-27 14:15:01.243 Demo[6090:10a03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:

dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable

Referenced from:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

Expected in:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation

if i don't have the iPhoneSimulator 5.1 SDK, can i do something for that those error message  when running at iOS 5.1 ？

Comment: I just encountered the same problem with Security.framework.  I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: i reset my project's Architectures to armv7 and armv7s & deployment target to 4.3 and clean rebuild solve this issue.